# grouping nodeList elements into separate Groups

Tags: javascript, html, foreach, nodelist

I have following nodeList

```
['<div class="item">1</div>', '<div class="item">2</div>', '<div class="item">3</div>', '<div class="item">4</div>']
```

and following function which accepts the number of element for a group and generates group of elements wrapped by divs

```
function groupElms (nOfElms) {
  var count = 0;

  [].forEach.call(nL, function (item) {



    count++;
  });

}
```

lets say `noOfElms` is 2 then the function should generate Elements like this

```
<div>
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

if `noOfElms` is 3 it should be like

```
<div>
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

I dont understand how to achieve this. Please Could someone help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply loop through your items and place every `N` of them into a created wrapper like this:

```js
function groupNodes(list, groupBy)
{
  var list = [].slice.call(list);
  var parent = list[0].parentElement;

  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i += groupBy)
  {
      var lastWrapper = document.createElement('div');
      lastWrapper.className = 'wrapper';
      parent.appendChild(lastWrapper);
  
      [].forEach.call(list.slice(i, i + groupBy), function(x) {
          lastWrapper.appendChild(x);
      });
  }  
}

groupNodes(document.getElementsByClassName('item'), 3);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
</div>
```

Note that it is supposed that all of these items are siblings. Otherwise, they all will be moved to the parent of the first item.

It can be done even easier using jQuery `.wrap()` function:

```js
function groupNodes(selector, groupBy)
{
  var $list = $(selector);

  for (var i = 0; i < $list.length; i += groupBy)
      $list.slice(i, i + groupBy).wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
}

groupNodes('.item', 3);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @SameeraAbeywickrama I am glad to hear it. I have updated my answer with jQuery approach which is much shorter and simple, if it is suitable for you.

Answer (score 0):

use the following

lets say

```
var a = ['<div class="item">1</div>', '<div class="item">2</div>', '<div class="item">3</div>', '<div class="item">4</div>'];
```

then function should be written like the following

```
function groupElms (nOfElms) {
    var count = 1;

    a.forEach(function (item) {
    if(count == 1) {
       var tempDiv = document.createElement("div");
    }

    tempDiv.appendChild(item);
    if(count == nOfElms) {
       document.body.appendChild(tempDiv);
      delete tempDiv;
      count=1;
    }
        count++;
  });

}
```

Comment: Thanks Rajesh. This logic would work. But one thing to notice is that you cant call foreach on nodeLists. so `a.forEach` would not work. :)

Comment: Yeah i forget that Sorry then you can use `[].forEach.call(a, function (item) {
  
});`